# C Program to count keywords from a keyword text file in a separate file and display them

Tags: c

So this is a school assignment.  We are to write a c program that reads keywords from one file, and counts the number of times they show in a separate file. In this case the other file is a fake resume. I thought I had it but now I have hit a brick wall and am stuck.  Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
    /*Programmer: John S. Bolen*/
/*Date: 2/20/19*/
/*This program will read the keyword file, and count the number of times the keywords are found in the fake resume file and display it for the user*/


#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define CLS system("cls")
#define FLUSH flush()
#define ROW 50
#define COL 21



void flush() {
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}

//prototype
void checkResume(char list[ROW][COL], int foundCount[ROW], int wordCount);
void displayResults(char list[ROW][COL], int foundCount[ROW], int wordCount);
int getWords(char list[ROW][COL]);


main() {
    char keyWords[ROW][COL] = { 0 };
    int foundCount[ROW] = { 0 };
    int wordCount;

    wordCount = getWords(keyWords);
    checkResume(keyWords, foundCount, wordCount);
    displayResults(keyWords, foundCount, wordCount);
    PAUSE;
} // end main

void checkResume(char list[ROW][COL], int foundCount[ROW], int wordCount) {
    FILE *fptr;
    char fileName[50];
    char read[1024];
    char readPart[21];
    int i, j, k;

    // get filename
    printf("Enter file name for resume: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        // open file
        fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
        if (fptr == NULL) {
            fptr = fopen("fakeResume.txt", "r"); 
            if (fptr == NULL) {
                printf("Error Opening File!");
                exit(-1);
            } // end if
        } // end if

        // read a line of text
        while (fgets(read, 1024, fptr) != NULL) {
            // TO UPPERCASE
            for (j = 0; j < (int)strlen(read); j++) {
                read[j] = toupper(read[j]);
            }
             //FOR TESTING ONLY: printf("Resume word %s\n", read); PAUSE;
            for (j = 0; read[j] != NULL; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < 21; k++) // empty the tester
                    readPart[k] = 0;
                for (k = 0; k < (int)strlen(list[i]); k++) {
                    readPart[k] = read[j + k]; // fill the tester with the next part of the line...match letters of word

                }
                if (strcmp(readPart, list[i]) == 0) // do the comparison
                    foundCount[i]++;
            } // end for
        } // end while
        fclose(fptr); // file needs to be reopened for each word being checked
    } // end for i
} // end checkResume

void displayResults(char list[ROW][COL], int foundCount[ROW], int wordCount) {
    int i, j, total = 0;
    CLS;
    // find the total
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        total += foundCount[i];
    // top line
    printf("\n\t\t%c", 201);
    for (i = 0; i < 37; i++)
        printf("%c", 205);
    printf("%c\n", 187);

    // keyword lines
    for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        printf("\t\t%c %2i.) %s:", 186, i + 1, list[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < 20 - (int)strlen(list[i]); j++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("%3i times %c\n", foundCount[i], 186);
    } // end for

    // middle line
    printf("\t\t%c", 199);
    for (i = 0; i < 37; i++)
        printf("%c", 196);
    printf("%c\n", 182);

    // total line
    printf("\t\t%c Total Keywords Found:    %4i", 186, total);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("%c\n", 186);

    // bottom line
    printf("\t\t%c", 200);
    for (i = 0; i < 37; i++)
        printf("%c", 205);
    printf("%c\n\t\t", 188);

} // end displayResults

int getWords(char list[ROW][COL]) {
    int result = 0;
    FILE *fptr;
    char fileName[50];
    char string[1024] = { 0 };
    int i, j, k = 0;

    // get filename
    printf("Enter file name for keyword list: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    // open file
    fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        fptr = fopen("keywords.txt", "r"); 
        if (fptr == NULL) {
            printf("Error Opening File!");
            exit(-1);
        } // end if
    } // end if

    // get string---READ IN FROM THE INPUT FILE and store in one ARRAY
    fscanf(fptr, "%s", string); // this reads in everything

    // to UPPERCASE
    for (i = 0; i < (int)strlen(string); i++)
        string[i] = toupper(string[i]);

    // split the string
    for (i = 0; i < ROW && string[k] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; string[k] != ','; j++) {
            if (string[k] != ',')       // keep putting letters in the  
                list[i][j] = string[k]; // row until you hit a comma
            k++;
        } // end for
        k++;
    } // end for

    // find word count
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        if (list[i][0] != 0)
            result++;

    fclose(fptr);
    return result;
} // end getWords
```

These are the keywords from my keywords.txt file:

> Java, CSS, HTML, XHTML, MySQL, College, University, Design, Development, Security, Skills, Tools, C, Programming, Linux, Scripting, Network, Windows, NT

and here is the fake resume from my fakeResume.txt:

> Dawn Johnson Sometown, OH 43085 Home: 555-555-5555 | dj@somedomain.com | BeFound Profile @twitterhandle | LinkedIn |
>   Portfolio Link
>
> Web Developer
>
> Junior Web developer able to build a Web presence from the ground up
>   -- from concept, navigation, layout and programming to UX and SEO. Skilled at writing well-designed, testable and efficient code using
>   current best practices in Web development. Fast learner, hard worker
>   and team player who is proficient in an array of scripting languages
>   and multimedia Web tools. Technical Toolbox
>
> Web Tools: JavaScript, jQuery, CSS, PHP, HTML, XHTML, XML, AngularJS,
>   Bootstrap, Java, .Net, ASP.NET, Python, MySQL, GitHub, Apache Flex,
>   JavaFX, REST, SOAP, cPanel, Google Analytics, WordPress Adobe Creative
>   Cloud: Photoshop, Lightroom, Illustrator, InDesign, Experience Design,
>   Premiere Pro, After Effects, Animate, Dreamweaver, Fuse, Adobe Muse,
>   Acrobat Pro DC
>
> Education ABC UNIVERSITY -- Sometown, OH BS, Information Technology,
>   Concentration in Web Site Development, degree in progress
>
> Courses: Web & Multimedia Development Digital & Interactive Design
>   Graphic & GUI Design Search Engine Optimization (SEO) 3D Animation &
>   Agile Methodologies Web Content Management Internet Technologies
>   Compression Formats Audio/Video Editing System Security Web
>   Development Experience
>
> ABC CHARITY, Sometown Chapter -- Sometown, OH Web Developer, 2015 to
>   Present (summers)
>
> Volunteered as a Web developer for newly opened animal shelter.
>
> Co-developed a dynamic, secure Web site from scratch. Launched
>   visually appealing, user-friendly Webscape with interactive features
>   to optimize traffic, page views, site "stickiness" and user experience
>   (UX). Used SEO best practices to elevate organization’s Web presence;
>   achieved top 10 Google rankings on several highly competitive
>   keywords. Created online surveys, contests and donation forms that
>   boosted funding and organizational visibility. Helped drive $38K in
>   ecommerce revenues. Engineered innovative "Adopt-a-Pet" Web
>   application customized for mobile devices. Honored with "Volunteer of
>   the Year" award as a result.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: it returns only JAVA with 0 keywords, and doesn't include any others nor do i think the count is working....

Comment: OT: regarding: `main() {`  There are only two signatures for `main()`  They are `int main( void )`  and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice that they both have a returned type of `int`

Comment: OT: regarding: `read[j] = toupper(read[j]);`  There is a well known function: `read()`.  such C library functions should not be overlayed by local variable names

Comment: OT: regarding: `fclose(fptr); // file needs to be reopened for each word being checked`  Much better to use: `rewind( fptr );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Error Opening File!");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`..  When the error indication comes from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling: `perror( "my error message" );`  as that will properly perform the desired actions.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", fileName);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers: '%s' and/or '%[...]', always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also assures that there will not be any undefined behavior from a buffer overflow

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(fptr, "%s", string); // this buffers in everything`  Actually, this ONLY inputs until the first `white space` is encountered,  Suggest using `fgets()` to read in a line from the file at a time, then using `strtok()` to separate the words using a delimiter string of: "\n, " (note the space)  This gives 3 reasons to end a word.  A comma, a space, and a newline

Comment: regarding; `#define ROW 50
#define COL 21`  What if there are more that 50 words?  What if any one word has more than 20 characters?

Comment: the posted code fails to find words in the resume that are split across lines